# Trying to create a 100% height div in a Wordpress site with Divi theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, divi

I have a Wordpress site, that shows maps of fictional worlds. The maps are leaflet.js maps, that are displayed within a div called `map`. This div is not created with the divi frontend, but in a html file that gets included through a plugin shortcode. Basically the php plugin loads a bunch of map specific settings to provide to the leaflet map and shows some html.

Now I want this map div to be as high as possible without causing a scrollbar.

I've tried different things:

- `height: 100%` - does not show anything at all, apperantly an issue with the parent elements
- `height: 100vh` - way bigger than the screen and triggers a scrollbar
- `height: 74vh` - fits on my 2.5k screen but not on others
- setting height according to `window.innerHeight` is too large
- setting height according to `window.innerHeight` and substracting the pixel count of the header and footer is too large too

Whatever I try, I either get a scrollbar or a white stripe below my blue footer. You can see it live here: https://fictionalmaps.com/audience-map/?creator=1&map=KisandraShowCase

My latest - not working - iteration of the code I include with php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!-- meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" -->
    
    <!-- some css files are loaded here needed for the leaflet map itself - none should interfere with the map div -->

    <style>
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1024px;
            height: 70vh;
            max-height: 1024px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
        var tempHeight = window.innerHeight;
        jQuery('#map').height(tempHeight);
    </script>

    <!-- some js files are loaded here needed for the leaflet map itself -->

</body>
</html>
```

This produces a scrollbar. If I try e.g. `var tempHeight = window.innerHeight - 340;` I can get it to fit nearly, but get a white stripe below the footer. Also it's not consistent across computers.

My CSS game is weak, I need some help! I'm stuck in an unsuccessful trial-and-error loop and running out of ideas what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute and give it a `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` that way iot will use the entire screen height.

```css
#fullscreen {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fullscreen"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not working in this context, unfortunately. The result looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/PZdcOnZ